# 自作Widgetが配置されたAppインスタンスを取得したい

Tags: python, kivy

この記事にあるように

[Kivyのrootについて](https://qiita.com/Agipy/items/6be3651b1200c1e3c677)

KV言語でappと書くことではAppインスタンスを参照できますが、KV言語ではなくPythonで書いたWidgetからAppのインスタンスを得るにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

Widgetごとにファイルを分けて、アプリケーションを作っていますが、設定値などウィジェットツリー全体でグローバル変数のように値を読み書きしたいです。
Appインスタンスにメンバとして設ければよいかと思ったものの、Appの参照方法で躓いてしまいました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

別な調べ物をしていた時に、この質問の解決策を見つけました。

[How to exit a Kivy application using a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425831/how-to-exit-a-kivy-application-using-a-button)

```
from kivy.app import App
App.get_running_app()
```

とすることで、Kivy言語内でappとしたものと同じオブジェクトが取得できるようです。

Answer (score 0):

```
Builder.load_string("""
<hoge>:
    app: app
""")

class hoge(Widget):
    app = ObjectProperty()
```

appプロパティを自作して、Kivy言語でセットすることでやりたいことはひとまず解決しました。